# IM and File Transfers Integrated With VoIP

Tags: file-sharing, voip, asterisk, instant-messaging

I have an Asterisk box serving an office of people. I'd like to provide instant messaging and file sharing capabilities alongside the voice and video capabilities provided by Asterisk (ala Windows Live Messenger, Skype etc). Asterisk does not seem to offer IM outside the context of a SIP call, nor am I aware that it provides file transferring capabilities whatsoever. The clients will be using Jitsi, so there are many protocols to choose from, but I'd like to provide as much integration as possible between the VoIP and IM/file transfer (ideally a single account that facilitates voice/video and IM/file transfer). Is this possible, and if not, what would be the most appropriate alternative?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if asterisk can handle instant messaging. However, Elastix.org provides a single CD installation of asterisk and openfire and other addons. Try http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/

Comment: Asterisk will do IM via SIMPLE, but not outside the context of a SIP call (which renders it practically useless from my perspective). My first thought was set up an XMPP server (i.e. Openfire, as is included in Elastix) alongside Asterisk. In my particular case the software will need to be installable (i.e. not a complete distro) as it will be running on a VPS, so I was hoping for a bit more integration than what running XMPP alongside would provide, but thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: I mentioned openfire coz it has an "Asterisk-IM Openfire" Plugin. However, I do not know the level of integration. Also, considering that is a java base xmpp server, it may not have dependency issues and you could install the provided binary.